# How to replace every char in a string value with the next char?

Tags: c#

If I have a string variable like this:

```
string f = "ABC";
```

I want to make it like this:

```
f="CDE"
```

This means that I want to take every char in this string and increase it to the next 2 values, if I have 'a' I want to change it to 'c' and so on.

Comment: What should happen to `'Y'` and `'Z'`?

Comment: it's just the idea of `char++;` I don't know what the char after 'Y' or 'Z'

Comment: @dtb I think that they will be `'['` and `'\'` based on the [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/). Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following will increment the character to + 2, Not sure what you want when then characters are ending character in the alphabets.

```
string f = "ABC";
string result = new string(f.Select(r =>(char) (r + 2)).ToArray());
```

For string `ABC` result will be `CDE`, but for string `XYZ` result will be `Z[\`

Comment: Hell, why do LINQ and lambda expressions always simplify things?

Comment: This is the correct answer concerning ascii a-z, A-Z. Albeit this won't work for y-z, Y-Z because it doesn't cover the edge case (y->a,z->b). This also won't work for non-alphabet characters or 'special' characters such as 'ë' because these characters are usually grouped together and this approach relies on the alphabetical grouping of a-z and A-Z.

Comment: @Shelakel because even the OP doesn't know how to deal with those situations, this is the best answer.

Comment: @Shelakel, the question doesn't mention anything other than alphabets and the edge cases

Comment: BTW I was actually thinking that using a `StringBuilder` and a loop could yield higher performance.

Comment: @Alvin : Linq and Lambda are like sugar , how much you need it, you decide ? overdose may lead to problems :)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is get the individual char from the string e.g.

```
string a = "aba";
char b = a[0]; //the value is equal to 'a'


Console.WriteLine((char)((int)b + 1));
```

then convert the char into an int and increament it then convert it back to a char

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the string to a `char[]`, modify each `char` as needed, and convert the result back to a string as follows:

```
char[] chars = "ABC".ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < chars.Length; i++)
{
    chars[i] += (char)2;
}
string result = new string(chars);
//    result == "CDE"
```